# Run PestPHP tests with Laravel Sail local setup

Tags: laravel, docker, phpunit, laravel-sail, pestphp

My `Laravel` local setup with Sail is using `pgsql` as database, so everything get orchestrated by `sail up`. Now I want to write tests by using `sqlite` in memory because the testing pipeline finally should not require to spin up a Postgres server nor I want to introduce database tenants to the codebase just for the sake of testing.

I have setup everything correct according to the docs of larvel and pest. Everything works to the point where I am verifying if the user registration is working and if the user got actually saved to the database.
From the error message I can tell that the test would like to connect to the Postgres server inside docker instead of creating an in memory sqlite database. `EnvironmentTest.php` is passing while `RegistrationTest.php` is failing in both methods.

*Please, if I get something completely wrong tell me as for me PHP, Laravel and overall Testing is new. Also I am open to any kind of suggestions.*

| Function | Error |
| --- | --- |
| render:registration | Expected response status code [200] but received 500. Failed asserting that 200 is identical to 500. |
| function:registration:register | Illuminate\Database\QueryException : SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not translate host name "pgsql" to address: Name or service not known (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_catalog = laravel and table_schema = public and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE') |

**RegistrationTest.php**

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature\Auth;

use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;


test('render:registration', function () {
    $response = $this->get('/register');

    $response->assertStatus(200);
    $response->assertInertia(fn($page) => $page->component('Auth/Register'));
});

test('function:registration:register', function () {
    $response = $this->post('/register', [
        'name' => 'Test User',
        'email' => 'test@example.com',
        'password' => 'password',
        'password_confirmation' => 'password',
    ]);

    $this->assertAuthenticated();
    $response->assertRedirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
});
```

**EnvironmentTest.php**

```
<?php

it('environment:testing', function () {
    expect(env('APP_ENV'))->toBe('testing')
        ->and(env('DB_CONNECTION'))->toBe('sqlite');
});
```

**CreatesApplication.php**

```
trait CreatesApplication
{
    public function createApplication()
    {
        $app = require __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap/app.php';

        $app->make(Kernel::class)->bootstrap();

        return $app;
    }
}
```

**phpunit.xml**

```
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
        <env name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
    </php>
```